# Query in PHP not working when using variables

Tags: php, mysql

This query works fine:
`$query = "SELECT * from hired WHERE username = 'kaas' and dvd = 'dvd 2'";`

But then I change it to this query:
`$query = "SELECT * from hired WHERE username = " . $_SESSION['name'] . " AND dvd = " . $_POST['dvd'];`

and it doesn't work, even though the values should be the same as the top query. It goes straight to my error message, *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '2' at line 1*

The dvd's are having names like 'dvd 1' 'dvd 2' 'dvd 3'. Why is it not working? Is there anything wrong in my query?

I tried to use the query with the data written down instead of using the session and post. It worked as I expected, and showed me an echo.

Comment: _"Why is it not working?"_ - because the single quotes used as delimiters for these text literals, don't magically appear on their own. _"Is there anything wrong in my query?"_ - that you are still trying to insert data into a query directly, is simply _fundamentally_ wrong these days - use _prepared statements_.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are not wrapping your string values in quotes
2. You must use prepared statements for security reasons (SQL Injection and escaping invalid values

```php
$query = "SELECT * from hired WHERE username = :name AND dvd = :dvd";

$statement = $pdo->prepare($query);

$statement->execute([':name' => $_SESSION['name'], ':dvd' => $_POST['dvd']]);
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score -2):

It needs to be

```
$query = "SELECT * from hired WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['name'] . "'" . "AND dvd = '" . $_POST['dvd'] . "'";
```

I forgot to put a ' around them, so it would see it (for example) as 'username = Fal' instead of 'username = 'Fal'

Comment: Please use prepared statements. Now your code is open to SQL Injection and does not even escapes possible quotes in strings.

Answer (score -2):

You have to concatenate variables inside query properly. Try this it will work.

```
$query = "SELECT * from hired WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['name'] . "' AND dvd = '".$_POST['dvd']."'";
```